# middleware not returning errors in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I have a middleware that uses `express-validator` to validate request,

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");

module.exports = {
  validate: (req, res, next) => {
    const raw_errors = validationResult(req);

    if (raw_errors.isEmpty()) {
      return next()
    }
    const errors = raw_errors.errors.map((err) => ({ message: err.msg }));

    return res.status(422).json({ status: "error", errors });
  },
}
```

I use it on the route like so:

```
const { validate } = require('../middlewares/validation')

routes.post('/', validate, (req, res) => {
    postService.add(req.body.name, req.body.description).then(post => {
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'post added', data: post })
    }).catch(error => {
        handleError(error, res)
    })
})
```

But when i try to make an API call with an empty request body, it does not return any errors.

Here is my model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide a name'],
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide a description'],
    }
},
{timestamps: true}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Here is my `postService`

```
module.exports = {
    //adds a post
    add : async  (name, description) => {
        try{
            const tab = { name, description }
            return postModel.create(tab)
        }
        catch(err){
            throw new ErrorHandler(500, "Unable to add post at this time. Please try again later.")
        }
    },
}
```

When I log `raw_errors` from the middleware, I get - `Result { formatter: [Function: formatter], errors: [] }`

Please what might be wrong?

Comment: put if condition - if(raw_errors.errors.length) to check error array of result object.

Comment: I can't see any validation middlewares before your `validate` middleware where you use `validationResult`. Your route should look like this for example `routes.post('/', body('name').exists(), validate, (req, res) => {` the `body('name').exists()` middleware add an error to `req` which the `validationResult` function reads. You only get an error if `req.body.name` is undefined.